# lock IBM SQL Database connection with IBM Data Studio

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, ibm-data-studio

I'm using IBM Data Studio 4.1.0.1 for maintaining for my IBM SQL database at IBM Bluemix.
For connection to my database I use the jdbc driver (JDBC 4.0)

When I connect to the database and I perform a select command, it isn't possible to connect to connect to the same database with another instance.

I think it would be weird that a IBM DB2 SQL database cannot handle multiple database connections for select queries.
If I perform a update or insert I can imagine that I have to do a commit.
But it is strange when I perform a select on the database, the database is locked.
Is this a setting within IBM Data Studio or do I have to set a setting when I create the database?

Comment: What does the "isn't possible to connect" look like?

Comment: Please provide us the exact error you are receiving and the steps you perform when getting the error